# "qwidget must construct a qapplication before a qpaintdevice" error for qt-vtk app in windows only

Tags: c++, qt, debugging, gdb, vtk

I know this is a common error and already answered in stackoverflow. But my problem is a bit different. While debugging my app on windows am getting this error. But in linux , the same code works just fine. in both the cases am using same vtk build 5.4 and same qt build 4.5 .
Even the system configuration is same. In windows , in release mode application runs just fine. Problem is in debugging only. Am using cmake/qtcreator/gdb toolchain.

Comment: Post `main()` or wherever you initialise `QApplication`.

Comment: Static variables or variables in unnamed namespaces are initialized on application start. So the QApplication can be not created at that moment. Linux and Windows can differ in initialization of those variables. You should ensure that any PaintDevices are created later than QApplication singletone object. I.e. when constructor of an object is called. Or you can use `lazy init`.

Comment: Ancient question, but I found the answer to this problem for my project here:
http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/10959-QWidget-Must-construct-a-QApplication-before-a-QPaintDevice

Make sure to only use release libraries when building release products. If you use a debug Qt library in release mode, it will give you the "QWidget: Must construct a QApplication before a X" error.